# Search all records created before 1-2 weeks ago?

Tags: report, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, fetchxml, advanced-search

I'm trying to create a report based on opportunities. One stat I'd like to see is opportunities that were modified but were not created this/last week, so I can see how many old opportonities have been worked on.

However on setting the filter criteria, the closest thing I can get to is "Older than X months", which will show all records modified but created more than a month ago.
Correct concept, but I need this to be 1 or 2 weeks.

I don't want to use "on or before" as you have to set a specific date. I need this report to be dynamic.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to write a little more careful. Correct spelling, indentation, capitalization will make your question more interesting to read and answer.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is to make dynamic the date inside the `On or Before` condition.

You can follow this tutorial:

[CRM Answers - "On or Before" and "On or After" conditions inside FetchXML Reports](http://www.crmanswers.net/2013/05/on-or-before-and-on-or-after-conditions.html)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you just use "on or before", and then calculate the date at runtime, based on the current date.